# How do I detect a user's IP address using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ip-address, mixpanel

I want to disable a script (mixpanel tracking software) for users from two unique IP addresses that are my AWS servers - is there a javascript function to do this automatically from the front-end?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
if (!(ipaddress1 || ipaddress2)){
    //run the script
}
```

Comment: What server-side language are you using?

Comment: Just don't include the script in the page that you deliver to your ASW servers - your server-side language should be able to do that easily. A javascript in a page cannot know to which IP it was delivered (or if at all?)

Comment: possible duplicate of this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript>

Answer (score 3):

There's no native way to do this, you'll need to use a service like [jsonip](http://jsonip.appspot.com/) (currently over quota) or you could make an AJAX request to your server (where you do have access to the requesting IP) and return it, bypassing the need for an external service.

Comment: The link your provided is over quota.

Comment: Yeah.  Fortunately it's easy to roll your own.  I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: That's a neat service but requires one to already know the IP.

Comment: @SomeKittens - I didn't actually read it in details... I just threw in the first result I found on Google :v